# npm install remote repository: fetch failed with status code 401

Tags: git, npm, gitlab

Trying to install remote package fails with status code 401,

npm/git doesn't prompt for gitlab credentials

i tried these two:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

none of them changed anything

cmd:

```
$ npm install http://gitlab.blabla.com/bla

npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.blabla.com/bla
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.blabla.com/bla
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.blabla.com/bla
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "http://gitlab.blabla.com/bla"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 401
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/bla/test/npm-debug.log
```

I expected npm to prompt me for remote access credentials but nothing.

How can i fix this prompt problem ?

EDIT: SSH Authentication is not an option.

EDIT 2: Adding credentials in URL doesn't work: same output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [SSH](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) protocol instead of http. You will need to generate [SSH keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#generating-a-new-ssh-key-pair). Then you will able to install:

```
npm install git@gitlab.blabla.com:bla
```

An alternative using http is to add credentials into the URL:

```
npm install http://username:password@gitlab.blabla.com/bla
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't because this repository isn't set for ssh authentication

Comment: Adding credentials in url doesn't work for me, same output